# web service error unexpectedly ending

Tags: json, web-services, jquery, iis-7, asp.net-4.0

I got following error when calling web service on IIS7, 64-bit, win server 2008:

> Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/getTopSixNewsByType'.

It is totally fine when the web is published on another server which is IIS6, 32-bit.

I tried put

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

into web.config but it didn't work.

The calling is

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/WebServices/NewsWS.asmx/getTopSixNewsByType",
     data: "{type:'1'}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     beforeSend: Loading,
     success: Success,
     error: Error
 });

 function Loading() {
     $('#gonggao').html('<img src="/Image/loader.gif"/>');
 }

 function Success(data, status) {
     $("#gonggao").setTemplateURL('/IndexPage/indexNews.htm');
     $('#gonggao').processTemplate(data.d);

 }
```

Can any one help me, Thank u!!

---

The code is in asp.net 4.0

---

Later I found another error message:

> Request format is invalid: application/json; charset=UTF-8

And solved it with adding following into web.config

```
<add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: Where did you find that other error message?